# Dimensions for manual cover & spine. I have them in inches

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I have a front and back manual 11" X 10" and the spine is 11" X 1 5/8ths" inches I'm thinking 600 dpi?  Does anyone know then what I say is the size I need?  I would appreciate it.

Would it different if made in photoshop as opposed to being made in adobe, or power point?  Just trying to educate myself so I'm asking for the correct thing!

Comment: I don't understand this question. Adobe is a corporation, not software. And that corporation makes more than 20 different applications, one of which *is* Photoshop. So "made in photoshop as opposed to adobe" makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 3):

It would depend on a few factors.  The best solution would be for you to contact the printer and select a paper, trim size, and quantity and they can help you with the spine thickness measurement.  Some printers even have auto generating templates that will ask you a few questions like this and can be able to output your measurements and even generate a template with a spine in it.  In regards to the DPI the typical standard is 300 but again, this would depend on a few factors so I would consult the printer.

In regards to Photoshop it is software provided by Adobe.  I think you need to research a little bit more and explain what exactly you're trying to do.  If you are trying to make a book I would suggest researching some of our questions and I would advise for you to use [adobe-indesign](/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign) for the layout.  We do have a tag for [book](/questions/tagged/book) that you might find some help in.